# What is the LG Motion 4G processor speed?

Tags: processor, lg-motion

According to the specs for the LG Motion 4G phone, it states the CPU speed should be 1.2Ghz. http://www.phonescoop.com/phones/phone.php?p=3779

But someone on android forums has reported that [this is not true](http://androidforums.com/5216305-post69.html), and the phone actually comes preloaded at 1.5Ghz.

Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

I just got a new LG Motion from MetroPCS, and before updating the system or anything, I used the app CpuSpy and it told me the CPU is 1.5Ghz.

Answer (score 1):

When I downloaded the app called CPU-Z, it said that my LG Motion has a 1.51 GHz MSM8960 Snapdragon S4 dual core. It also said that the CPU is called krait and comes with an Adreno 225 GPU. So, I believe that Metro PCS got their specs wrong about the LG Motion, CPU-wise.